# How to set button have image and shadow?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

To make shadow, make shadow xml file and use like `android:background="@drawable/shadow"`.
But put image is `android:background="@drawable/image` too.

how to set button shadow and image in one button?

I'm sorry I'm not fluent in English.

Comment: take imagebutton

Comment: you can add your button inside card view to get better shadow effect

Comment: I found a code make shadow. but It must use `android:background`option. but put image in button is use `android:background` too. I want to know how to use that at the same time...

Comment: you can user Imagebutton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. use ImageButton**

try this you can use `ImageButton` :- Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user. By default, an ImageButton looks like a regular Button, with the standard button background that changes color during different button states.

```
 <ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/btnMain"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:contentDescription="@string/btnMain_description"
  android:elevation="10dp"
  android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_fram‌​e"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"
  android:src="@drawable/IMage"
 />
```

**2. user CardVirew**
or you can try this add your `button` inside `card view` like this

**compile this dependencies**

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

**layout like this**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/disha"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Comment: at the ImageButton, the Image don't fill up completely. how to fix that?

Comment: @DongHyeongJeong check updated  ans user android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Of Course, I'm trying now :)

Comment: In CardView, How to add the shadow?

Comment: use app:cardElevation="10dp" to give shadow in cardview

Answer (score 2):

**create button_selector.xml in res/drawable :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
                    <solid android:color="#D6D6D6" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270" 
                        android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#BABABA" />
                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />
                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" 
                        android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    </selector>
```

**And in your xml layout:**

```
 <ImageButton
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CardView` to achieve this :

Add support lib to `dependencies` as follows:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'//Add respective version
  }
```

use this in layout

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/user_image"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="10dp" >
```

Please let me now if it helps.